# 1990s TV series featuring underwater habitat and girl with the ability to breathe underwater?

Tags: identify-this-tv-show

I'm trying to find the details of a TV show that was aired on British Morning Television in the mid to late 1990s.

I vaguely remember it being Australian, but that could simply be due to the number of Australian imports CBBC was fond of airing during the summer holiday.

The central plot was about some kind of underwater habitat where the occupants were studying some form of marine biology, and they all wore uniforms that made them look like Seaworld trainers.

I believe, from the freely available technologies (bathyspheres, advanced submarines) that it could have been set in the future, possibly after some kind of environmental incident.

Either way the protagonists were for some reason forbidden from going ashore, and yet seemed to manage it every episode.

A recurring character was a girl who was some kind of bipedal mermaid, and I think she was a mute... unless that part is just the little mermaid blurring into my memory.

Anyone know what this show was?

Comment: Sure it was nineties?  Sounds like Stingray http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stingray_(TV_series) to me

Comment: Sounds very much like Stingray ....... only 3 decades off, but like Thunderbirds it was repeated forever.

Comment: Was live action, definitely not stingray I'm afraid: although this now raises interesting questions about the derivation of the show I'm thinking of!

Comment: Mmm - now I'm puzzled.  Do you remember the channel it was on?

Comment: More than likely it was BBC2 in the UK, as they used to schedule hour upon hour of kids television during the School Summer Break. The more I think about it though, the more I'm sure it was an Australian show. It had reasonably good production values, and the Mermaid-Girl thing was a babe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could it be Australia's *Ocean Girl* (released as *Ocean Odyssey* in the UK)? It featured a character named Neri:

> Neri — the title character — is a young girl with an affinity for
>   water, super-human strength, the ability to swim long distances, and
>   super-human lung capacity. She lives alone on an otherwise deserted
>   island. Early in the first season, Neri befriends two Australian boys:
>   Jason and Brett Bates. This friendship is at first a highly-guarded
>   secret due to Neri's fear of other humans. The Bates brothers live in
>   an elaborate underwater research and environmental protection facility
>   called ORCA, located near Port Douglas, Queensland. At the beginning
>   of the series, they move to ORCA in order for their mother, Dr. Dianne
>   Bates, to study whale song. A significant portion of the series takes
>   place on ORCA itself, and looks at the activities of its inhabitants,
>   many of whom are school-aged children, just as Jason and Brett.
>   ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocean_Girl))

It ran from 1994-97, and a follow-up version ran in the early 2000s. Neri was played by Marzena Godecki:

[image]

(from oceangirl.org)

Answer (score 6):

A quick Google search suggests [Ocean Girl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocean_Girl) - it's an Australian TV show made between 1994 and 1997 which features a girl named Neri with "super-human lung capacity" who befriends some boys living in an underwater facility.